# Unable to Import "System.Web.Helpers"

Tags: c#, asp.net, docker, iis

I'm working on a project for my internship. We aren't the first group to work on this project, so we didn't build it up from scratch.

The problem we are currently facing is that we want to parse JSON data, but we can't get *System.Web.Helpers* to work.

The API doesn't have a project folder just seperate .aspx files and one master.master file. So debugging is very hard because we can only deploy it in a local docker container, so I can't use any breakpoints to see whats happening.

The way we now work is docker-compose -> server-live -> test aspx page -> see whats wrong -> change code

And this goes on and on.

My question is how can I get *System.Web.Helpers* to work because `<%@ Import Namespace="System.Web.Helpers" %>` doesn't work.

Comment: "The API doesn't have a project folder" is a red flag because it might use the legacy ASP.NET Web Site project type. Discuss with your supervisors and make an ASP.NET Web Application please. That should make your life much easier. Besides, remote debugging is not hard to configure, https://www.richard-banks.org/2017/02/debug-net-in-windows-container.html

Comment: Not sure why you need System.Web.Helpers to parse JSON. The industry standard has been using [Newtonsoft Json.NET](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) and [System.Text.Json](https://www.fuget.org/packages/System.Text.Json) is the new challenger that everyone seems to be switching to.

Comment: If you can't figure out how to debug your apps *without* a debugger, then you probably have inadequate logging in the code. You should investigate libraries like [Serilog](https://serilog.net/) and [NLog](https://nlog-project.org/). You can combine that with a logging platform like [Seq](https://datalust.co/seq) (which can run in Docker), which will let you quickly find logs relevant to whatever you need.

Comment: @mason unable to use System.Text.Json. **Error thrown**: 
`The type or namespace name 'Json' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Text'`

**Implementation**: 
`<%@ Import Namespace="System.Text.Json" %>`
`<%@ Import Namespace="System.Text.Json.Serialization" %>`

Comment: You can't just add import statements and expect consuming libraries that aren't part of the framework to just work. Importing brings the namespace into scope, but won't go and obtain the assemblies for you. That's what [NuGet is for](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/what-is-nuget).

Comment: @mason So for NuGet to work there need to be a project structure right? Otherwise I can't implement them. Currently there is no project just a folder with different files. I already asked my supervisor about creating a project but he hasn't responded yet.

Comment: You can use NuGet without a project structure. Open your website in Visual Studio and I believe it will still let you manage NuGet packages. Anyways -why wait for your boss? You're using source control right? Git? Just make a new branch (`git checkout -b my-new-branch`), convert it to a Project from a website, and you'll be good to go. If they say no (why would they?) then you can just delete the branch and move on.

Comment: @mason Thank you very much for you quick responses and helpfull feedback